# I have issue with variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I don't I understand the I am beginner in JavaScript I tried so many options and don't get what is wrong can someone help me.

```
var myFriend = "John";
function greetings() {
 "Greetings ${myFriend}"
}
console.log('results: ', greetings());
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
module.exports = greetings;
}
```

I tried many options on `Greetings` I can not get what is wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `return` before `"Greetings John."`

We use `return` in a function to return a value,
for example

```
function sayHello(name){
   return "Hello "+name+" !";
}
alert(sayHello("jhon")) //OutPut: Hello jhon !
```

*Snippet*

```js
var myFriend = "John";
function greetings() {
 return "Greetings John.";
}
console.log('results: ', greetings());
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
module.exports = greetings;
}
```

More About `return` : [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp)

Comment: Thank you I haven't pay attention to the assignment correct also the assignment should be somehow accented. I will pay attention more to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
module.exports = greetings;
}
```

What are you trying to achieve here ?
Beside, it seems that your "John" variable isn't used at all, as the message is hardcorded.

```
function greetings() {
 "Greetings John.";
}
```

Here if you wanted to display a different name that would be

```
function greetings(myFriend) {
 console.log("Greetings" + myFriend + ".")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @N_R01 said: use `return` .. also you doesn't use the **myFriend** variable anywhere.
It could be used like this:

```js
var myFriend = "John";
function greetings() {
  return `Greetings ${myFriend}.`;
}

// OR

function greetings(friendsName) {
  return `Greetings ${friendsName}.`;
}

// this would be called like
greetings("Peter")
//-> "Greetings Peter"
```